# How to fix error when concatenating two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying the following:

```
rands = np.empty((0, 10))
rand = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, 10)
rands = np.concatenate((rands,rand),axis=0)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

But why is this error? Why can't I append a new row `rand` into the matrix `rands` with this command?

**Remark:**

I can 'fix' this by using the following command:

```
rands = np.concatenate((rands,rand.reshape(1, 10)),axis=0)
```

but it looks not pythonic anymore, but cumbersome...

Maybe there is a better solution with less brackets and reshaping...?

Comment: Well although `rands` has initially an empty row it is still 2 dimensional the shape is `(0,10)` which is why it borks

Comment: Yes, and a row is one-dimensional with 10 elements. I don't understand what the problem is here...

Comment: Not in numpy's eyes it isn't you'd still get the same error with `rands = np.empty((1, 10))`

Comment: what about: 
`rands = np.empty((1,10))`
`rands = np.concatenate((rands[0],rand),axis=0)`

Comment: no does not work. I will add more rows later, I have to repeat this concatenate line multiple times, in a loop

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Your 'fix' will produce a 2-D array with a shape of `(1,10)` you could've changed your random array to this `
rand = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, (1,10))` and it would've worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rands` has shape `(0, 10)` and `rand` has shape `(10,)`.

```
In [19]: rands.shape
Out[19]: (0, 10)

In [20]: rand.shape
Out[20]: (10,)
```

If you try to concatenate along the 0-axis, then the 0-axis of `rands` (of length 0) is concatenated with the 0-axis of `rand` (of length 10).
Pictorially, it looks like this:

rands:

```
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

rand:

```
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
```

The two shapes do not fit together well because the 1-axis of `rands` has length 10 and `rand` lacks a 1-axis.

To fix the problem, you could promote `rand` to a 2D array of shape `(1, 10)`:

```
In [21]: rand[None,:].shape
Out[21]: (1, 10)
```

So that the 10 items in `rand` are now laid out along the 1-axis. Then

```
rands = np.concatenate((rands,rand[None,:]), axis=0)
```

returns an array of shape `(1, 10)`

```
In [26]: np.concatenate((rands,rand[None,:]),axis=0).shape
Out[26]: (1, 10)
```

Alternatively, you could use `row_stack` without promoting `rand` to a 2D array:

```
In [28]: np.row_stack((rands,rand)).shape
Out[28]: (1, 10)
```

Comment: I like row_stack. And now it looks more pythonic.Thanks!